# int assignment to char in string reverse function in K&R book?

Tags: string, int, variable-assignment

I was reading K&R and found a function used to reverse strings. It seems to be assigning an int to a char and vice versa. I am wondering how and why this is possible? I am aware I am likely to be missing something quite obvious.. hopefully not. 
First post btw.

```
void reverse (char s[])
{
   int c, i, j;

   for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
   c = s[i];
   s[i] = s[j];
   s[j] = c;
}
```

c is an int and it's being assigned to a char in an array?
Am I understanding that part correctly? 
What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

`char` and `int` are just integer types, meaning they represent a whole number. So if I have

```
char x = 2;
int y = 3;
```

If I set `x = y`, what happens? Just what you'd expect, `x` gets the value `2`.  What may be confusing you is that `char`s are just numbers. If I have:

```
char x = 'a';
int y = x;
```

What does `y` hold? The [ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the character `'a'`, which happens to be 97 (decimal; `0x61` in hex). And what does `x` hold? 97, same as y. Characters are nothing but a number, that happens to appear under certain circumstances as a shape you see on the screen and recognize as a letter (or digit, or punctuation mark).

The difference comes in when you hit numbers above the largest `char` (255 / 0xff on most machines). Above the maximum for their type, numbers just wrap around (256 -> 0, 257 -> 1, 258 -> 2, etc.)

Comment: Well explained. I definitely understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, in `C`, an `int` was pretty freely used as a general purpose value. It's just a integer number. Technically, `char` was just a smaller, 8-bit number. You could even declare an `int x` then assign `x = 'a'` if you want. Strict typing wasn't traditionally a big deal in `C`. So, yes, you could assign an `int` to a `char` as long as you know you're not exceeding a value of 255 (unless you really intend to). Older compilers wouldn't even complain. Modern `C` compilers, by default, will at least warn you about the implicit typecast.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks a lot.